# items about "would like to post to Facebook for you"

Tags: facebook, review, publish-actions

I write a program that says "Program would like to post to Facebook for you"
what item should i submit for review?
is that "publish_actions"?

but Facebook just say "It looks like you haven't made any API requests to publish content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days. You, or any account from Roles, needs to test this app with this permission before you can submit it for review."

Then I add my account to testers and test the program,but nothing changed, why?
what should i do?

Comment: post the code you already have and someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The message "Program would like to post to Facebook for you" appears because you're requesting the publish_actions permission during login. It sounds like your app doesn't actually make use of this permission though.

Keep in mind that if you're using a dialog or button to share content (for example the Share Dialog, Like Button, Send Button or Message Dialog), the publish_actions permission is not used as the actual sharing is done by the Facebook app. The publish_actions permission is only used if you're directly posting to Facebook from your app via the Graph API by calling /me/feed or a similar endpoint.

If you're only using dialogs or buttons to share, you don't need to request the publish_actions permission during login and your app doesn't need to be reviewed for this permission.

Comment: If you use a button to share, does that mean that you don't need any special permissions from Facebook? How to submit your application for review in that case (without any permission selected)?

Comment: @cakan: If you're not using any permissions from Facebook, you don't need to submit your app for review unless you want to list it on the App Center. The Share button doesn't need your app to be reviewed before you can use it.